# How do I associate an Elastic IP Address to a Windows Server in an AutoScale Group Automatically?

Tags: windows, powershell, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to find an example of way to reliably associate the same Elastic IP Address to a Windows Server that is part of a AutoScale Group.  Essentially the goal is to deal with situations where the server gets terminated and replaced via AutoScale and maintain the same Public IP (required for a remote provided service).

The AutoScale Group is configured to only allow 1 server max and 1 server minimum for an automatic recovery scenario.  Server is in a VPC and is essentially a worker for a remote web queue that requires the static addressing.

I'd like to also leverage IAM roles so that I don't have to embed AWS credentials in a UserData provided script.  Currently I'm looking for an example powershell script but if someone knows a better way, I'm open to suggestions of course.  I've seen some older examples out there but they are dated and are using embedded AWS credentials which I'd like to avoid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what we use:

In the Launch Configuration of the Autoscaling Group, specify the following user data:

```
<script>
PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile -File c:\tools\server_userdata.ps1 -instanceEIP eipalloc-abcdefg
</script>
```

That passes the EIP identifier `eipalloc-abcdefg` to the script. Change that to your EIP of course.

We prebake the userdata script itself on the instance, rather than passing the full script to the user data. We normally do alot of configuration in this script; I have reduced it to only EIP assignment here. With a prebaked script, we can share the same script over a variety of instance functions and environment, and control configuration of that instance by passing parameters only via the user data, nothing is statically coded in the script.

Also note we use a transcript file, and Windows events log entries to simplify troubleshooting.

**c:\tools\server_userdata.ps1**

```
<powershell>
Import-Module WebAdministration
Start-Transcript -Path C:\userscriptlog.txt
param (
    [string]$instanceEIP = $(throw "-instanceEIP is required."),
)
if ([System.Diagnostics.EventLog]::SourceExists("Userdata") -eq $False) {
    New-Eventlog -Logname Application -Source 'Userdata' 
}
Write-Eventlog -Logname Application -Source 'Userdata' -EventId 1 -EntryType Information -Message 'Begining post-deployment configuration script'

# get instance-id
try { 
    $InstanceId = (Invoke-WebRequest http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id).content
} catch { 
    $_.Exception.message | out-file c:\InstanceId_error.log 
    Write-Host "FATAL: InstanceId exception"
    Exit 1
}

if (!$InstanceId) { 
    Write-Host "FATAL: InstanceId is null"
    Exit    
} else {
    $InstanceId | out-file C:\InstanceId.txt
    Write-Host "InstanceId: $InstanceId"    
}

Write-Host "EIP: $instanceEIP"

# assign EIP

$request = New-Object -TypeName Amazon.EC2.Model.AssociateAddressRequest
[void]$request.WithInstanceId($InstanceId)
[void]$request.WithPublicIp($instanceEIP)

$result = $client.AssociateAddress($request)
if ($result) {
  Write-Host  "Address $instanceEIP assigned to $instanceID successfully."
  exit 0
}
else {
  Write-Host  "Failed to assign $instanceEIP to $instanceID."
  exit 2
}

Write-Eventlog -Logname Application -Source 'Userdata' -EventId 1 -EntryType Information -Message 'Post-deployment configuration script complete'
Stop-Transcript
</powershell>
```

Regarding IAM roles, this script assumes the instance has the appropriate role and permissions. Here are the required permissions:

```
{  
   "Version":"2012-10-17",
   "Statement":[  
      {  
         "Action":[  
            "ec2:AssociateAddress",
            "ec2:DescribeAddresses",
         ],
         "Sid":"Stmt1375723773000",
         "Resource":[  
            "*"
         ],
         "Effect":"Allow"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: This appears to be exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you! In the time since I posted the question, I had also recalled that AWS had launched Cloud Watch Events earlier this year which would provide an off box solution to the objective.  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/WhatIsCloudWatchEvents.html

Comment: @Rodrigo Where do you define your server_userdata.ps1 file?

Comment: @Rodrigo M Hi! Is there a way to get the EIP ID via AWS CLI from a pool of unallocated EIPs?

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps I needed an Auto Scaling Group to maintain a single instance behind a single IP (so that an external service could whitelist requests from my server by IP). I solved it by allocating an Elastic IP then adding a startup script in the Create Launch Configuration -> Configure Details -> Advanced Details -> User data:

```
#!/bin/bash

# configure AWS
aws configure set aws_access_key_id {MY_ACCESS_KEY}
aws configure set aws_secret_access_key {MY_SECRET_KEY}
aws configure set region {MY_REGION}

# associate Elastic IP
INSTANCE_ID=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)
ALLOCATION_ID={MY_EIP_ALLOC_ID}
aws ec2 associate-address --instance-id $INSTANCE_ID --allocation-id $ALLOCATION_ID --allow-reassociation
```

If the instance ever goes south, the Auto Scale Group spins up a new instance which reclaims the same Elastic IP and the whitelist is still valid. (This is basically the approach Shlomo Swidler and Bless@AWS were suggesting, just in a little more detail. :-) )

For those that want a pool of addresses, it may be possible to extend this approach to use ‘aws ec2 describe-addresses’ and choose one that isn’t assigned to an instance.

Comment: Thanks, I'm actually looking for a Windows Powershell example similar to your example but minus also the need to embed the AWS credentials as this Launch Configuration does associate an IAM EC2 Role.  I'm new to powershell as most all of my environments are Linux.  This need is for a migration of an existing Windows solution currently in a data center and moving to AWS.